# How to delete from the database using JQuery and Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have the following code with an if statement depending if a user has saved an article or not. I'm simply trying to delete the article from the database using jquery. I unsure where im going wrong? help is much appreciated!

View:

```
<form action="{{URL::route('article-delete')}}" method="post" id="article_one_delete">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" name="first_desc" value="{{$firstrow->description}}" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" name="first_title" value="{{$firstrow->title1}}" class="form-control">
</div>

<button type ="button" id="Recodelete" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">UnSave</button>
{{Form::token()}}

</form>
```

Route:

```
Route::delete('/home/', array( 'as' => 'article-delete', 
'uses' => 'HomeController@deletearticle'));
```

Controller:

```
public function deletearticle(){

 $firsttitle       = Input::get('first_title');

$articledelete  = UserSaveArticle::where('user_id', Auth::id()
 ->where ('user_save_articles.chosen_title', $firsttitle))->delete();

return true;
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Recodelete').on('click', function(){
       var article_one_delete = $('#article_one_delete').serializeArray();
       var url_d         = $('#article_one_delete').attr('action');

       $.get(url_d, article_one_delete, function(data){
           console.log(data);
       });
    });
 });
```

Comment: have you got any error?

Comment: In your controller try:   ->where ('chosen_title', '=', $firsttitle)->first();   and then $articledelete->delete();

Comment: No, the database gets updated with Null values instead of the row deleting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should define right route for DELETE article, like this:

```php
Route::delete('/article/{id}', ['as' => 'article-delete', 'uses' => 'HomeController@deleteArticle']);
```

2. In the `HomeController` $id variable (article ID) will be available as a method parameter:

```php
function deleteArticle($id)
{
    …
}
```

3. In PHP side you defined DELETE route, it means you should make DELETE request on JS side using the [ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) method:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/article/' + articleId,
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks limonte. I'm actually in the process of re-designing my database. Your solution is a lot better!